# What's wrong with this function? It crashes my program with no error

Tags: c++, string, function, loops

Since I made the function `void logoff_check()` the program crashes with the first (correct) input with no errors when compiling. I don't see anything wrong.

I know I'm not explaining well. If you need more details of the problem just comment and I will explain the best that I can. I'm new in programming and I'm studying computer science by the way.

This is the function:

```
void logoff_check(string username, string lab1[], string lab2[], string lab3[], string lab4[], bool& logoff)
{

for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
{
    if (lab1[i] == (username + " ") && i < 5){
        lab1[i] == "";
        cout << "\n\n\t\t\tLog Off Successful.\n\n";
        logoff = true;
        break;
    }
    else if (lab2[i] == (username + " ")){
        lab2[i] == "";
        cout << "\n\n\t\t\tLog Off Successful.\n\n";
        logoff = true;
        break;
    }

    else if (lab3[i] == (username + " ") && i < 4){
        lab3[i] == "";
        logoff = true;
        cout << "\n\n\t\t\tLog Off Successful.\n\n";
        break;
    }

    else if (lab4[i] == (username + " ") && i < 3){
        lab4[i] == "";
        cout << "\n\n\t\t\tLog Off Successful.\n\n";
        logoff = true;
        break;
    }
}

}
```

Here's the rest of the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cctype>
#include <cstring>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

void input(string& username, bool& userDigit);
void admin(string[], string[], string[], string[]);
void user(string username, string[], string[], string[], string[]);
void screen(string[], string[], string[], string[]);
void search(string ID, string [], string [], string [], string [], bool& notfound);
void logoff_check(string username, string [], string [], string [], string [], bool& logoff);

int main()
{

string username("");
const string Admin_key("ADMIN");

string lab1[5] = { "", "", "", "", "" };
string lab2[6] = { "", "", "", "", "", "" };
string lab3[4] = { "", "", "", "" };
string lab4[3] = { "", "", "" };

char ans;
bool digitID = true, 
    end = false, 
    inputbool = false, 
    logoff = false;

do
{

    cout << endl;

    input(username, digitID);

    logoff_check(username, lab1, lab2, lab3, lab4, logoff);

    if (Admin_key == username && !logoff)

        admin(lab1, lab2, lab3, lab4);

    else if (digitID && !logoff)

        user(username, lab1, lab2, lab3, lab4);

    else if (!logoff)

        cout << "\nBad input data!\n";

    cout << "\n\nTo continue hit Enter or press Q to exit\n";

    cin.ignore();
    cin.get(ans);

    if (ans == 'q' || ans == 'Q') //alternate end because the program never ends with this condition
         end = true;              //in the do-while loop. I dont know why.

} while (!end);

    return 0;

}

void input(string& username, bool& userDigit)
{
//Function Body
}

void admin(string lab1[], string lab2[], string lab3[], string lab4[])
{
//Function Body

}

void user(string username, string lab1[], string lab2[], string lab3[], string lab4[])
{
//Function Body
}

void screen(string lab1[], string lab2[], string lab3[], string lab4[])
{
//Function Body
}

void search(string ID, string lab1[], string lab2[], string lab3[], string lab4[],bool& notfound)
{
//Function Body
}
void logoff_check(string username, string [], string [], string [], string [], bool& logoff)
{
//Function is above
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're going past the end of your arrays, because you have your guards backward:

```
if (lab1[i] == (username + " ") && i < 5){
```

should be:

```
if (i < 5 && lab1[i] == (username + " ")){
```

The `&&` operator performs short-circuit evaluation, and you do definitely need it here, because each of your arrays is a different length.

Putting the test *after* you've already tried to index the array isn't terribly useful.